# Ajax to load table data

Tags: ajax, load

Request your help, as the below line of code if not loading the data into the table when i choose the related radio button, not sure what is wrong nor missing, if there is any alternate way other then this please do let me know.

**Code**

```
<div>
<label class="form-check-label><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="Gender" value="M" checked>Male</label>
<label class="form-check-label><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="Gender" value="F" checked>Female</label>
</div>
<div class="row" id="Dbackup">
<table id="Backup">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th><th>Gender</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>xxxx<</td><td>Male</td></tr>
.
.
<tr><td>xxxx<</td><td>Female</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

**Ajax script**
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type='radio']").on('click', function(){
    var radioValue = $("input[name='Gender']:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
            url: "/gdata/" + radioValue,
            method: "GET",
            data:{rvalue:radioValue},
            success: function(data){
                     $('#Backup').load(data);
                    }
   });
});
});
</script>
```

From,
Vino

Comment: You have to use append() instead of load.

Comment: Hi, If i use apped it load both data Male and Female but i need only one data at a time: Choosen: Male : list Male only, Choosen: Female : list Female only but not both.

Comment: Its because you are returning data of both male and female from url: "/gdata/" + radioValue. Kindly post code of the URL part also.

Comment: Url: /gdata/ + radioValue : is call a PHP function getData($radioValue) , with a simple SQL: "SELECT NAME from registration where gender = ?";  and return's $data; unset($data);

Comment: Hi, Was able to resolve the issue, thank you very much.